# How can I hide a spinner after a while?

Tags: c#, wpf, spinner

I wanna put a spinner loading and after a while (about 3, 4 seconds) to hide it. How can I do it?

```
   <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="10" Background="White"Name="spinner">
   <fa:ImageAwesome Width="80" Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" SpinDuration="2" />
   </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure XAML solution, without any code behind:

```
<StackPanel ...>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3"
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>

    <fa:ImageAwesome .../>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `x:Name` attribute of the element in XAML:

```
<fa:ImageAwesome x:Name="MyIcon" Width="80" Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" SpinDuration="2" />
```

And in code behind:

```
private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Create a timer with interval of 3 secs
    dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);

    MyIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    // Start the timer
    dispatcherTimer.Start(); 
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    // Stop the timer
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you should either call Start and Stop, or set IsEnabled to true and false. Mixing both looks odd.